# Calling function in directive

Tags: angular

I am trying to call a public function which is inside my directive from component by getting hold of the directive via viewchild like this

```
 @ViewChild('myDirective') myDirective;
 ....
 myDirective.nativeElement.myFunction();
```

But I get error that the myFunction does not exist.
Is there a way to call a function which is iniside a directive?

Comment: checkout this as well
https://netbasal.com/angular-2-take-advantage-of-the-exportas-property-81374ce24d26#.fxcc4c7vf

Comment: This shows how you can do it using a template variable: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36345948/222748

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**[DEMO - How to call Directive's function from Component](https://plnkr.co/edit/hONSHQpNbhK3J4r9RIl2?p=preview)** - *check browser's 
console*

---

**1)** I hope you are ***importing myDirective directive***.

```
import {myDirective} from './Directive';
```

**2)**

```
@ViewChild(myDirective) vc:myDirective;   ///<<<@@@removed '' from ('myDirective')
```

**3)**

```
ngAfterViewInit(){   
    this.vc.myFunction();                 ///<<@@@ no need to use nativeElement
}
```

**4)**  Or some button's click event

```
click(){
   this.vc.myFunction();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked with ViewChild and by setting the directive instead of the #myDirective I was using with the ''. But it makes wonder how to accomplish this when using multiple directives. In this case I am only using one directive.

Comment: With multiple directives mean how and what???. Ask question and get answer. tell us your scenario and we'll try to resolve it.

Comment: Thanks, what I mean is if you have e.g. from your plunkr
 <h2 someDirective> Angular2</h2>
 <h3 someDirective> Test 3</h3>

How would you reference the h3 directive

Comment: Could you please ask it as a separate question?

Comment: just what i was looking for, awesome find!

Comment: @doorman You could try `@ViewChildren(Type)` instead then call ToArray and access by index.

Comment: This seems deprecated. Cannot read property 'callme' of undefined. please see https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-playground-1di2vk?file=app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 9):

Use `@ContentChild()`. A directive doesn't have a view.

Call `this.myDirective.nativeElement.myFunction()` in `ngAfterContentChecked()` to ensure that `this.myDirective...` is already initialized.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I changed ViewChild to ContentChild but now myDirective is undefined. Any idea why this could be happening?

Comment: Did you find out why?

Comment: A directive doesn't have a view, it only can have content - the content of it's host element.

Comment: with ngAfterContentChecked, check for not null and not undefined using "if (this.vc) {this.vc.myFunction()}" - checked for ng5 & ng6

Comment: that should be accept answer. Your solution help me so much. thank alot.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "exportAs" property of the directive to then get the directive's instance from the decorated component.

For instance:

Create a dummy directive:

```js
import { Directive } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  standalone: true,
  selector: '[appDemoDirective]',
  exportAs: 'aDirective' // add here a name to get the instance later

})
export class DemoDirective {
  aFunction(aParameter: string) {
    console.log(aParameter);
  }
}
```

You can then get the directive instance using #variableName='aDirective'; i.e. a variable name = the export name you gave above

```js
const template = `
<button appDemoDirective #directiveRef='aDirective' (click)="directiveRef.aFunction(message)">Click me</button>

`
 
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: template
})
export class AppComponent {
  public message = "Hello";
}
```

Clicking on button should call the directive's function and print "Hello" in this case